# product page stuck on loader sometimes

Tags: product-page, loader

I am using magento 2.3.4

My product page loader gets stuck randomly.
It doesn't happen all the time, but happens consistently.
Also, it occurs only on configurable products page.

Let me know how to solve this issue..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you check the magento log file or console?

Comment: Yes, I am getting different js error each time I load the page

Comment: Is that error from which file?

Comment: Sometimes my console return the following errors, 
1. Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(u){var n,o=window.Slick||{};n=0,(o=function(e,t){

Comment: Also, 
2. 166 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(e,s){var t=e.create("masonry");t.compatOptions.fitWidth="isFitWidth";e=t.prototype;return e._resetLayout=function()